# "Pages" property of .doc file not set

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get page count from multiple word documents by selecting them in a folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/499309/get-page-count-from-multiple-word-documents-by-selecting-them-in-a-folder)

I've got about 10,000 Word 97 files (in .doc format) which I need to put into separate folders depending on how many pages each file has (they're going to be posted to customers and, apparently, this makes it easier for the printer to put them in envelopes).

I was expecting this to be easy. If I look at the files in Windows Explorer in Details view, then I can add the "Pages" column and sort by it and then select all the documents with one page and drag the files into the appropriate folders, then select all the documents with two pages, etc.

However, although this works for other .doc files I have on my PC, it doesn't work for these 10,000 that have been generated. The Pages column is blank. When I look at the document properties, the Pages field is blank there too.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there an easier way to achieve my aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/499309/get-page-count-from-multiple-word-documents-by-selecting-them-in-a-folder/501550) question as it seems like a duplicate.

My answer there should be able to assist.