# Counting pages within Word [.doc] documents

Tags: microsoft-word, script, automation, vba

I'm trying to find a way of listing the number of pages within multiple word documents, all saved within the same folder. Is this possible using VBA?

I am using:

- Windows 7 and
- Microsoft Office 2007

Comment: Please give us some more details; what version of Word? what have you already tried? Does it have to be VBA? If so, post some code you are working with.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Word 2007. I haven't tried anything, my research has revealed some vba sub routines that are associated to this task but don't provide a solution. I specified VBA since I thought it would be possible to loop through all the necessary documents but don't have the expertise to produce any code like this.

Comment: Would be good if you updated your question with the info you provided above, ie win office 2007 etc

Comment: Thank Deesbek, I've added some further information regarding my system. I'll add this level of detail to future posts thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in VBA (in Word itself) but you could create a small VBS-file and drop it in the directory and double click it:

```
Const wdStatisticPages = 2
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
currentPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(currentPath)
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
For Each Fil In FLD.Files
    If UCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(Fil.name)) = "DOCX" Then
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(currentPath & "\" & Fil.Name)
        intPages = intPages + objDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
        objDoc.Saved = True
        objDoc.Close
    End If
Next
objWord.Quit
Wscript.Echo "Total pages: " & intPages
Set oShell = Nothing
Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Assuming the files are all `.docx` extension.

Inspiration (and explanation) came from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/07/how-can-i-get-a-total-page-count-for-all-the-word-documents-in-a-folder.aspx). For simplicity i didn't use `objWMIService` but just went with `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. You can also set `objWord.Visible = False` to `True`. You'll see the Word-application flickering on and off.

You can also show the pages in "Windows Explorer". Just right-click the columns above the files and choose more, you can select `pages` to show a column with the pages per Word-document. So you can see the page-count before opening the document. (You'll need to be in the `Details`-view to see the columns)

If you really want you could also translate this yourself to VBA (Word-macro).

Comment: Thank you so much Rik, you've now encouraged me to learn VBS!

Answer (score 0):

See my [previous answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/499309/get-page-count-from-multiple-word-documents-by-selecting-them-in-a-folder/501550#501550) - this may help.

It IS possible to achieve, technically, but not always reliable - especially without being (computationally) expensive, which nobody ever wants - and my answer explains why.